# Java Search all paths of nodes with same label from root

Tags: java, tree, nodes

I am trying to write JAVA code which returns path of all nodes which have same label.

In the [image specified in link](http://www.hypertextbookshop.com/dataminingbook/public_version/artifacts/images/pictures/chpt2interSec6Fig1.jpg). I should get following o/p for label C

**A->B**

**A**

as output.

I know all possible label's. Say labels can range from A to J.

Tree's Node class is :

```
class Node{
 String label;
 int count;
 List<Node> children;

 public int hashCode() {
    return label.hashCode();
 }

 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Node other = (Node)obj;
    return other.label.equals(label);
 }
}
```

I am trying something like

```
for(each label)
 start from root
 search for all possible label location
    print path for each label location
```

But not able to understand how to write the code. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<List<String>> findPaths(String label) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    if (label.equals(this.label)) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    for (Node child : children) {
        for (List<String> subResult : child.findPaths(label)) {
            // add this.label in front
            List<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
            path.add(this.label);
            path.addAll(subResult);
            result.add(path);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Each path will be encoded as a `ArrayList` of `String` labels. I'm assuming that each leaf has an empty list of children. If `children == null` in leafs, you need to check for that, or the loop over all children will raise a `NullPointerException`.

Now, given some list of labels `labels` and a root node `root`:

```
for (String label : labels) {
    List<List<String>> paths = root.findPaths(label);
    for (List<String> path : paths) {
        printPath(path);
    }
}
```

I trust you can make your own function `printPath(List<String> path)` to print the actual path...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Code worked fine for me.

I wrote simplest printPath function  

 
    private void printPath(List<String> path)
    {
     for(int i=0;i<path.size();i++)  
     System.out.println(path.get(i));    
    }